# I am trying to structure my application but getting an error

Tags: angular

I am trying to structure my application but getting an error:
"Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property"

```
ERROR in ./src/app/views/home/home.component.ts
Module build failed: Error: G:\Test\HelloWorldAngular\HelloWorld.Angular\src\app\views\home\home.component.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (G:\Test\HelloWorldAngular\HelloWorld.Angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:674:23)
    at plugin.done.then (G:\Test\HelloWorldAngular\HelloWorld.Angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Comment: please write a question

Comment: This issue happens when I separated the router.module in a file outsource from app.module then added it as a reference in @NgModule( imports

Comment: come on - this is not a question. provide your source code, detailed information and a valid question

Comment: thanks, Niyou, I got why their error happened. It's because I split the app.module into two files "the main one and another one for routing. So the old components have been created got a conflict between the two files. Therefore when removed all old components and recreated again the issue was solved.